# Как сформировать документ word по SQL запросу?

Tags: sql, plsql, ms-word, аналитика

Требуется часто готовить документацию, в связи с этим возник вопрос. Есть ли готовое решение или каким способом можно автоматизировать создание документа word описание в котором будет описание SELECTa или другой конструкции PL/SQL?
Например,

```html
SELECT id1, id2, id3 from table1 where id1 = 1
```

Результат после автоматизации:
Документ с таблицей

| Поле | Значение | Условие |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Id1 | table1.Id1 | WHERE id1 =1 |
| Id2 | table1.Id2 |  |
| Id3 | table1.Id3 |  |

Пояснение:
При каждой доработки пишется документация, и если код, который уже существовал в проекте не описан, то приходится выполнять очень трудоемкую работу по описанию кода в определенном формате, в частности переносить код в табличный вид. Для большего понимая, в таблице описаны поля для разработчика, конкретных значений там нет. Условие указано так как в таблице, т.е. WHERE и т.д.
Эта задача касается оптимизации части описаний, которые делают аналитики. Хотим упростить им работу.

Comment: Дык это ж фактически свой парсер нарисовать! я уж не говорю о том, что реально в такую конструкцию таблицы кладутся только простейшие плоские запросы...

Comment: А зачем Word, а почему не текстом? Лучше читать?

Comment: @0xdb все спецификации аналитики описывают в формате обычных вордовских документов, это единственная причина. если я правильно понял в текст, это в обычный блокнот txt, там таблицы будут состоять из символов, это уже не очень читабельно для бизнес-аналитиков и др. ролей.

Comment: Например, здесь на ресурсе все таблицы с данными предложены текстом, даже у вас в текущем вопросе. Никто не жалуется. Предпологаю, что у вас "плохо воспитынные" аналитики. По теме, никаких готовых решений, скорее всего, вы не найдёте. Генерируте XML в виде Word таблиц и упаковывайте их как Word документ.